# .NET assembly distribution method that avoids file blocking

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, software-distribution

I'm distributing .NET assembly in `.zip` archive on my project web pages.

When the assembly is downloaded using Internet Explorer and extracted using Windows Explorer, the `.dll` is marked as insecure and cannot be loaded. The error message is

> Could not load file or assembly 'file:///...\WinSCPnet.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported.

One has to go to file Properties and click *Unblock* button. Note that the assembly is digitally signed.

[image: Unblock button]

Is there any way to prevent that? It looks like downloading the file from `https://` helps. But that's not an option for me, at least not in a short term. Maybe some other packaging format?

Comment: Nowadays, you probably just want to publish on NuGet instead ;-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only option is to create installer (msi/exe/clickonce). IE/Explorer will track any files downloaded, and there is no way to disable it at server side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot to mention that I wanted to avoid creating an installer as I consider it overkill for distributing a library.